# You have an error in your yaml syntax on line 10

Tags: yaml, github-actions

i'm trying to exectute that github workflow but something is wrong with syntax...

```
name: Build and Script
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: [ubuntu-latest]
  steps:
    - name: checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: "executing remote ssh commands using ssh key"
      uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
      with:
        host: '${{ secrets.HOST }}'
        username: '${{ secrets.USERNAME }}'
        password: '${{ secrets.PASSWORD }}'
        port: '${{ secrets.PORT }}'
        script: whoami
```

Thank you in advance for help

Comment: What happens if you remove the `name` portion of the first step and just have `- uses: actions/checkout@v2` in that step?

Comment: The YAML looks okay. Please provide more info, e.g. how exactly does the error message look and when do you get it. Also make sure that you don't have tabs in your YAML file that may not have survived copying it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `steps` directive is not properly indented - it should be indented one more tab (2 spaces).

```
name: Build and Script
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: [ubuntu-latest]
    steps:
    - name: checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: "executing remote ssh commands using ssh key"
      uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
      with:
        host: '${{ secrets.HOST }}'
        username: '${{ secrets.USERNAME }}'
        password: '${{ secrets.PASSWORD }}'
        port: '${{ secrets.PORT }}'
        script: whoami
```

In addition - although not an issue - you do not need an array syntax for `runs-on`. The below is also fine.

```
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
```